# how do i add input on python on repl.it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

So my issue is that I wrote import to the file on the program but it says invalid syntax can anyone tell me what the issue is

Comment: `print("\n\t\t\t\t\t "Import=listone "")` is not legal python code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, in future please include your code as text, not in a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot have multiple `"` in one string.

You need to print it with `'` or use `'''` and it will work:

```
print('\n\t\t\t\t\t "Import=listone "')
```